# string add number c++

Tags: c++, string

I have `string arr` and `int abc`. I want to connect number that number to the end string

```
string arr="Hello";
int abc=123;
arr=arr+itoa(abc);
cout << arr;
```

Comment: Use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using to_string

```
string arr="Hello";
int abc=123;
arr=arr+to_string(abc);
cout << arr;
```

Or using stringstream

```
string arr="Hello";
stringstream ss;
int abc = 123;
ss << arr << abc;
cout << ss.str();
```

Comment: I use the second. but I want to take back the number

Comment: @QuânTiến So use `istringstream` and parse the number back